# How accurate are JMeter results

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I am using JMeter to test my web application.
I am able to run test and can see results using various listener.
To reduce resource when i run with more than 1000 thread i run jmeter in non gui mode and after completion of test view the result in graph mode.
I want to know how accurate are Jmeter results(average/median response time).
Let suppose if 1000 users are using my web application and they have response time of 20 ms.
If i simulate 1000 users using JMeter and then see average ,median time in Jmeter.
Since JMeter is creating lot of threads and has its own processing , is it possible that average/media response time  in JMeter is higher than actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with every load tool, you need to control your injector :

- regarding OS config (tcp, system tuning ...)
- machine power
- injector runtime behaviour as of cpu, swap ...

If your injector is in good state, results will be accurate.

See:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubikloadpack-advised-tuning-for-injector-when-load-testing-video-streaming-servers/